# Using jQuery Ajax and Mysql to produce HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to build a bit of a dynamic photo gallery. I am trying to move away from the traditional HTML/PHP refresh constantly to see updates by introducing some jQuery to do some dynamic MYSQL queries.

So far (note I am a beginner) I have a page which uses some jQuery to send a call to a PHP file which contains some basic PHP code for querying the database. The results of this are then *appended* to a div with a certain ID.

But my problem is, that with this method, there is no generated HTML code... if I view source on the page, containing thumbnails as a result of my jQuery/MYSQL query, there is no HTML source for the thumbs.

This leads to my biggest problem...trying to incorporate jQuery Masonry. Masonry needs some HTML elements to modify (I think), but there aren't any, so it doesn't work.

Hopefully someone understands what I am trying to do and will have a better way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The modification done to HTML using jquery ajax cannot be seen in the view-source. You can retrieve the data from the tags you have generated using their ids, but the browser cannot understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `echo` html content in `php` file, then in `ajax` `success` you could `append` to certain `div`

eg.

```
echo '<img src="img.jpg" alt="image"/>';
```

In your `ajax`

```
success: function (data) { // img tag echoed from php file
            $('#youDivID').html(data);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing (although I used .append not .html - but has same result). Still results in no code in the source code so Masonry doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Elements are created by appending, but when you looks on source code they are not yet added. Because javascript not been run yet.

You may see them in chrome dev tools. Just click right mouse button on element and select "Inspect element". About the same way works in firebug and safari dev tools.

Comment: Is there some way of initialising the Masonry after the image divs have been appended?.. or something like that?

Comment: You can do that in your ajax "success" method.